# Compile a Cython project and clean

Tags: python, cython

I'm using:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("myfile.pyx"))
```

to compile `myfile.pyx`. Is there a way to:

1. Have the `.pyd` in the current folder (instead of `build/` subfolder)
2. Clean after compile (i.e. delete `build/` subfolder, delete the `.c` file)

*without having to do it myself with `os.remove(...)` ?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `--inplace` option:

```
--inplace (-i)       ignore build-lib and put compiled extensions into the
                     source directory alongside your pure Python modules
```

`setup.py clean` should clean the build dir. `setup.py clean --all` cleans all build output.

Comment: How is it possible to set `inplace` *not* from command-line, but directly inside `setup.py`'s content?  Can I put `inplace` as a parameter in `setup(ext_modules = cythonize("myfile.pyx"))` ?
Same question about `clean` : is it possible to trigger `clean` from Python code?

Comment: In a shorter way: I'd like that simple `python setup.py` does inplace + clean  automatically.

Comment: Ok. Something else. Any idea why I get: `error: option --inplace not recognized` when doing `python setup.py build --inplace`

Comment: Last thing: about deleting the temporary `.c` file, I have to remove it myself, right?

Comment: Looks like. Just add the deletion to your `make` file.